# Prime radical that is nil but not nilpotent

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, nilpotence

Please help me to show that the prime radical of the ring $R=\prod\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  { \mathbb{Z} /2^n\mathbb{Z} } $ is nil but not nilpotent.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? Can you see that the prime radicals of the *finite* products $\prod_{n=1}^{N} \mathbb{Z}/2^n\mathbb{Z}$ are nilpotent (but with nilpotent power depending on $N$)? I think that would help. Of course, that the prime radical is nil is an elementary result in commutative algebra.

Answer (score 2):

If $\sqrt{0}^n=0$, then in particular $(2 e_n)^{n-1}=0$, i.e. $2^{n-1} = 0 \bmod 2^n$, a contradiction.

Comment: @Martin...Thanks a lot!